# How does Git monitor files? How would it know if something "unexpected" happens?

Tags: git, file, version-control

When working on a local repo, how does Git know when a file is modified?

How would it know if something "unexpected" happened. For example, what if part of the disk (SSD) failed and a file got truncated?

Also, how would you know if your local Git repo database (or whatever it is) became corrupted?

Comment: Git probably computes checksums for each file and stores them. If something changes, then Git finds where each file went and what changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git uses the SHA1 hash function to ensure integrity of the repo contents. The 40 character commit ID you see is actualy the output of the hash function. I think it is the combination of file contents, parent commit hash, commit message, commit time, commit author that gets hashed.

Comment: So `git status` causes it to calculate the checksum for every file?